# returning multiple values using php to jquery.ajax with json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i'm trying to make a simple call to data from database using php and ajax. I need multiple results. hence i'm using json method. But its not working.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: "qid=162",
  url: "activity_ajax.php",
  dataType: json,
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data.first);
  }
});
```

My activity_ajax.php page returns the following

```
echo "first":"Steven","last":"Spielberg","address":"1234 Unlisted Drive";
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can send multiple data in an array  and then use **[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**

```
$output =  array('first'=>'Steven',
                 'last'=>'Spielberg',
                 'address'=>'1234 Unlisted Drive');

echo json_encode($output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

and on other side you can access the value by this way

```
 success : function(resp) {(
              alert(resp.first);
              alert(resp.last);
              alert(resp.address);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks diCho. it solved the issue. I was missing those "" at dataType: "json" parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your not returning valid JSON ... change your PHP to this :

```
$temp = array('first' => 'Steven', 'last' => 'Spielberg', 'address' => '1234 Unlisted Drive');
echo json_encode($temp);
```

and it will return valid JSON.

The [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) method returns valid JSON from a variety of sources (an associative array being one)